# Selenium web driver not loading webpage in firefox

Tags: php, yii, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get Selenium Web Driver to work with php using the Yii framework.

phpunit is installed and working.

I have the latest version of selenium server running. (selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar)

I have [this Yii extension for web driver installed](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/webdriver-test/).

I have this shell test.

```
Yii::import('ext.webdriver-bindings.CWebDriverDbTestCase');

class SiteTest extends CWebDriverDbTestCase
{
    public function testExample() {
        $this->get("http://www.example.com");
        $this->assertTrue($this->isTextPresent('Example Domain'));
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

When I run it on the command line with

```
phpunit functional/SiteTest.php
```

The test runs. A firefox window opens with an empty profile (with the web driver plugin installed.) But the webpage doesn't load. There is nothing in the address bar. Nothing happens at all. The browser stays open, meanwhile the command line prints the following.

```
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\full\path\to\yii\project\protected\tests\phpunit.xml

F

Time: 4.88 seconds, Memory: 3.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) SiteTest::testExample
Failed asserting that false is true.

C:\full\path\to\yii\project\protected\tests\functional\SiteTest.php:18

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

I'm on windows 7 and have tried turning off the firewall to see if that was the cause.

As you can see phpunit is working fine as the second test passes. But for some reason firefox is not opening the requested page.

Edit: I'm using the latest release of php (5.5.5)

Edit: I've now also tried with the Chrome Driver. I get the same result. Chrome opens but the page does not load. The address bar just has 'data:,' in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue whenever I launch my scripts with the newest server nothing happens. But I noticed that if I use selenium server v2.33 everything works again (http://goo.gl/cxpyd2). However, I have been getting a execute js error that appears to happen with the new firefox and with 2.33? I am not sure. So I assume that it was fixed with the newer version of the server but I am not able to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem however downgrading the firefox version to 11.0 it started working. If you use linux you can use synaptic and force a firefox version downgrade